# help in probability question

Tags: probability

On a five-hole whack-a-mole cabinet. After each pop a mole would pop again from any random hole. You bet your friend you will get at least one correct guess in 4 attempts.  Is this a good bet for you to make? What are the odds?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  what is the chance you are wrong on one pop?  To not get a correct guess, you need to be wrong four times in a row.

Answer (score 1):

Probability of a correct guess is $\frac{1}{5}$. Hence probability of a wrong one is $1-\frac{1}{5}$. The probability of all wrong guesses in 4 attempts is $(1-\frac{1}{5})^4$. Hence the probability of ata least one success is...